# Using a char variable in tr///

Tags: perl

I am trying to count the characters in a string and found an easy solution counting a single character using the `tr` operator. Now I want to do this with every character from a to z. The following solution doesn't work because `tr///` matches every character.

```
my @chars = ('a' .. 'z');
foreach my $c (@chars)
{
    $count{$c} = ($text =~ tr/$c//);
}
```

How do I correctly use the char variable in `tr///`?

Comment: I would do this a bit differently, you can replace any character that is not something from [a-z] with nothing and count the remainders.

Comment: I want to know how many there are of each character, not of the whole character class.

Comment: Now you have 2 problems? Is there some reason you don't want to just iterate through `$text` and increment each letter's counter as you see it?

Comment: In my opinion Wooble's comment is a more efficient way to do this than any of the answers below (so I gave an up :) )

Comment: I've read that `tr` is much faster than iterating over the text.

Comment: Thanks for all your fast answers. I've voted for eugenes because it's the simplest and closest to what I wanted.

Comment: @André: `tr` is undoubtedly faster than iterating when you're replacing one set of characters with another. Doing 26 `tr`s, on the other hand, almost certainly won't be (although I haven't benchmarked).

Comment: Agree with @Wooble. Using this approach is by far an inefficient way to do this. Also, you're missing uppercase characters here.

Comment: OK, good to know. Uppercase is no problem because i did an `lc()` before. Didn't post it because it's irrelevant ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`tr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) doesn't support variable interpolation (neither in the search list nor in the replacement list). If you want to use variables, you must use `eval()`:

```
$count{$c} = eval "\$text =~ tr/$c/$c/";
```

That said, a more efficient (and secure) approach would be to simply iterate over the characters in the string and increment counters for each character, e.g.:

```
my %count = map { $_ => 0 } 'a' .. 'z';

for my $char (split //, $text) {
    $count{$char}++ if defined $count{$char};
}
```

Comment: This works fine. Could you explain why there is a backslash before `$text`? I'm new to perl :-)

Comment: André: it prevents interpolation of the `$text` variable in the string, i.e. `eval` sees the string as `'$text =~ tr/a/a/'`

Answer (score 7):

`tr///` doesn't work with variables unless you wrap it in an `eval`

But there is a nicer way to do this:

```
$count{$_} = () = $text =~ /$_/g for 'a' .. 'z';
```

For the TIMTOWTDI:

```
$count{$_}++ for grep /[a-z]/i, split //, $text;
```

Comment: Thats a nice solution for my problem but it doesn't answer my question how to use the regex with the variable. So I had to accept eugenes answer. Sorry!

Comment: @André : `tr///` is *not* a regex operation, though the construct may look similar

Comment: Note that if any of the characters you're searching for are regex metacharacters (like `.`, `?`, `*`) instead of just a-z, you need to escape them in the first solution. You can do this by adding `\Q` to the regex: `$count{$_} = () = $text =~ /\Q$_/g for '.', '?', '*';`

Comment: These two methods aren't quite the same.  The first method (searching for `$_`) will produce a hash with 26 keys --- one for every letter in the alphabet --- regardless of whether those letters appear in `$text`.  The hash produced by the second method (using `grep`) will only have key-value pairs for keys that appear in `$text`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) for `tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr`, then you'll see, right at the bottom of the section, the following:

> Because the transliteration table is built at compile time, neither the SEARCHLIST nor the REPLACEMENTLIST are subjected to double quote interpolation. That means that if you want to use variables, you must use an eval():

```
eval "tr/$oldlist/$newlist/";
die $@ if $@;
eval "tr/$oldlist/$newlist/, 1" or die $@;
```

Thus, you would need an eval to generate a new SEARCHLIST.

This is going to be very inefficient... the code might feel neat, but you're processing the complete string 26 times. You're also not counting uppercase characters.

You'd be better off stepping through the string once and just incrementing counters for each character found.

Answer (score 1):

From the [perlop documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> ```
> tr/AAA/XYZ/
> ```
>
> will transliterate any A to X.
>
> Because the transliteration table is built at compile time, neither
>   the SEARCHLIST nor the REPLACEMENTLIST are subjected to double quote
>   interpolation. That means that if you want to use variables, you must
>   use an eval()

Alternatively in your case you can use the `s///` operator as:

```
foreach my $c (@chars) {
   $count{$c} += ($text =~ s/$c//g);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution with some modification based from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=446003

```
sub lowerLetters {
    my $string = shift;
    my %table;
    @table{split //, $letters_uc} = split //, $letters_lc;
    my $table_re = join '|', map { quotemeta } reverse sort keys %table;
    $string =~ s/($table_re)/$table{$1}/g;
    return if not defined $string;
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `s` instead. Substitution is much more powerful than `tr`

My solution:

```perl
$count{$c} =~ s/\$search/$replace/g;
```

`g` at the end means "use it globally".

See:

- https://blog.james.rcpt.to/2010/10/25/perl-search-and-replace-using-variables/
- https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch09_06.htm